# Wordpress : redirect all .pdf to one page

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, migration

Following migration to a wordpress I would like all the old addresses [www.mondomaine.fr/pages/files/PDF/*.pdf](http://www.mondomaine.fr/pages/files/PDF/*.pdf) towards [www.mondomaine.fr/catalogue](http://www.mondomaine.fr/catalogue)

I tried with several syntaxes of REDIRECT but it adds the name of the pdf file in the new URL so I end up with a 404

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^pages/files/PDF/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).pdf /catalogue [L,R=301]